# Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists when enable apc

Tags: magento, apc

I'm facing this problem on my site Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists when I enable APC, Please help me how to solve this error.

After pecl install apc, I enabled apc.so in /etc/php.d/apc.ini.

```
extension = apc.so
```

and restart httpd.
then it said :There has been an error processing your request

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists";i:1;s:852:"#0 /var/www/html/testsite/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
```

I have tried every way but not get the success.